# How to create layout like in this image?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

***I want to know how can I create this layout in Android? Blur background and listView with Album art? What data I need to fetch?***

[image]

My current layout looks like this.
[My app layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akmYP.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="#FF330000"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

           <ListView
                     android:id="@+id/song_list"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </ListView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

And the below Java code maps the song layout

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      //map to song layout
      LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout)songInf.inflate
  (R.layout.song, parent, false);
     //get title and artist views
     TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
     TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
     //get song using position
     Song currSong = songs.get(position);
      //get title and artist strings
      songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
      artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
     //set position as tag
     songLay.setTag(position);
     return songLay;
    }
```

Comment: learn about  different layouts and drawables.

Comment: you want listView with image?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. any resources?? @Radix

Comment: @shivampandey can you post your listView layout ?

Comment: yes @Tony the image is Album cover art.

Comment: it is attached http://i.stack.imgur.com/akmYP.png

Comment: Look on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/user/slidenerd, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl

Comment: @shivampandey I want the xml code

Comment: I think he wants a transparent background

Comment: @Tony XML attached? its just simple ListView.

Comment: @shivampandey check my answer

Comment: @RuchirBaronia i think its blur, not transparent.

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tony. I am integrating it in my app, if it works i will surely inform you.

Comment: @shivampandey no problem

Comment: @Tony your answer helps but it disabled the play feature, and i can't figure it out any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is this what you want. You may try.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Depeche Mode"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="Remixes 81-04"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark_nodisable"
                android:text="12 songs  1:18:53"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Amount" />



        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey tony your code worked but before that the song were playing but after the modifications the songs are not playing. i have added the java code to the question. The Linear Layout should be changed accordingly but How?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to solve your next problem :(